# Word request (historical) - net worn by ancient soldiers

Tags: single-word-requests, etymology

I am looking for a word for a net worn by soldiers in ancient times hanging down from their helmets, sometimes too long as resting on shoulders. (Please, refer to the picture annotated by red arrow posted below this text.)

I read about it a long time ago on Wikipedia, and as I recall the net was used for ornamental purposes. I cannot find that Wikipedia article. There is a specific word for this type of net worn by soldiers on their helmets in historical times.

[image]

Comment: in general the word Ger *Harnisch* comes to mind, though not exclusive, or not at all applicable to helmets

Comment: strange! my questions had 2 answers but now all answers are gone. I accepted one of the answers.